# How to sort date columns that have empty cells

Tags: javascript, sorttable.js

I'm using the sorttable.js script found at http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

One problem I'm having is that sorting isn't working on my date columns that have a mix of empty cells and dates.  My dates are in "MM/DD/YYYY" format.

From what I can see, the sort is occurring here in the script:

```
sort_mmdd: function(a,b) {
    mtch = a[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; d = mtch[2]; m = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt1 = y+m+d;
    mtch = b[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3]; d = mtch[2]; m = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt2 = y+m+d;
    if (dt1==dt2) return 0;
    if (dt1<dt2) return -1;
    return 1;
  }
```

What I can't figure out is how to make the blank cells either go all to the top or to the bottom when a sort occurs on the column.

Any ideas on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get the dates to work alongside blank cells (see below).

Ultimately tested "mtch" before using it later...

```
sort_mmdd: function(a,b) {

    mtch = a[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);

    if ((mtch == null) || (mtch == undefined)) {
        y = 0; d = 0; m = 0;
    }
    else {
        y = mtch[3]; d = mtch[2]; m = mtch[1];
    }

    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt1 = y+m+d;

    mtch = b[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);

    if ((mtch == null) || (mtch == undefined)) {
        y = 0; d = 0; m = 0;
    }
    else {
        y = mtch[3]; d = mtch[2]; m = mtch[1];
    }

    if (m.length == 1) m = '0'+m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0'+d;
    dt2 = y+m+d;
    if (dt1==dt2) return 0;
    if (dt1<dt2) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could return an array when there is no match  that is either far in the future or far in the past...

```
mtch = a[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE)|| ['nomatch','01','01','9000'];
```

Comment: +1 - thanks for this.  It's the right idea (and helpful), but didn't quite work right.  I think that maybe "a[0].match..." is returning undefined...either way, I figured a way to do it and will post my answer in a moment.  Feel free to comment on it what may be able to be improved in it.

Comment: Just checked out your profile and found out you're a fellow Mainer - it's a small world after all!  I saw your name was "kennebec" and that seemed suspicious to me...I live in Brunswick; haven't been to Readfield yet...